# Do I need to install the same reference/dependencies across multiple namespaces to solve this FileNotFound exception? (C#)

Tags: c#, reference, dependencies

I'm following along with a Tim Corey tutorial on making a Tournament Tracker WinForm app (this one at this point, in case it helps - https://preview.tinyurl.com/yxmyz8h6)

I've gotten to the point where we are starting to hook up the class library to SQL using some NuGet packages - namely Dapper, System.Data.SqlClient & System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

So far the project is split across two namespaces, the class library that holds all the models and data access classes (TrackerLibrary) & the form UI (TrackerUI). I was under the impression from the tutorial that these references only need to exist in the class library and not in the UI (as TrackerLibrary is where Tim directed us to add them)

But without them referenced in the TrackerUI - a FileNotFoundException shows up for all three when you run the code. However, that doesn't happen to him in the tutorial.

The SQL connection string is set up in the App.Config file of the TrackerUI and looks like this...

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Tournaments" 
   connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=TournamentTracker;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

There is a class in TrackerUI called CreatePrizeForm that has a button click method to validate the form a user completes and then turn that data into a model and pass that model into SQL...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TrackerLibrary;
using TrackerLibrary.Models;

namespace TrackerUI
{
public partial class CreatePrizeForm : Form
{
    public CreatePrizeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void createPrizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidateForm())
        {
            PrizeModel model = new PrizeModel(
                placeNameValue.Text, 
                placeNumberValue.Text, 
                prizeAmountValue.Text, 
                prizePercentageValue.Text);

            
            GlobalConfig.Connection.CreatePrize(model); 
            

            placeNameValue.Text = "";
            placeNumberValue.Text = "";
            prizeAmountValue.Text = "0";
            prizePercentageValue.Text = "0";

        }
```

GlobalConfig class handles deciphering whether we are saving to SQL or saving to a Text File as per the imaginary client requirements for the tutorial and grabs the connection string, which looks like this...

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Text;
    using TrackerLibrary.DataAccess; 
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Dapper;

    public static class GlobalConfig
{
    public static IDataConnection Connection { get; private set; }

    
    public static void InitializeConnections(DatabaseType db)
    {
        if (db == DatabaseType.Sql)
        {
            
            SqlConnector sql = new SqlConnector();
            Connection = sql;
        }

        else if (db == DatabaseType.TextFile)
        {
            
            TextConnector text = new TextConnector();
            Connection = text;
        }
    }

    public static string CnnString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

The IDataConnection interface looks like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using TrackerLibrary.Models;

namespace TrackerLibrary.DataAccess 
{

public interface IDataConnection
{
    PrizeModel CreatePrize(PrizeModel model);
}
}
```

And the CreatePrize method looks like this...

```
    using Dapper;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Text;
    using TrackerLibrary.Models;

    public class SqlConnector : IDataConnection
    {
   
    public PrizeModel CreatePrize(PrizeModel model)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new 
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString("Tournaments")))
            {
            var p = new DynamicParameters(); // Dapper object
            p.Add("@PlaceNumber", model.PlaceNumber);
            p.Add("@PlaceName", model.PlaceName);
            p.Add("@PrizeAmount", model.PrizeAmount);
            p.Add("@PrizePercentage", model.PrizePercentage);
            p.Add("@id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

            connection.Execute("dbo.spPrizes_Insert", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            model.Id = p.Get<int>("@id"); 

            return model;
          
        }
```

The error occurs when the code reaches here...

```
GlobalConfig.Connection.CreatePrize(model);
```

With the following exception...

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

When I installed the System.Data.SqlClient NuGet package into the TrackerUI's references - it errors at the same point as before but this time it talks about Dapper...

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Then if you then install Dapper into TrackerUI references, it gets past the GlobalConfig.Connection.CreatePrize call into SqlConnector.cs and errors on the using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection... line below...

```
using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using TrackerLibrary.Models;

namespace TrackerLibrary.DataAccess
{
public class SqlConnector : IDataConnection
{
      public PrizeModel CreatePrize(PrizeModel model)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString("Tournaments")))
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters(); // Dapper object
            p.Add("@PlaceNumber", model.PlaceNumber);
            p.Add("@PlaceName", model.PlaceName);
            p.Add("@PrizeAmount", model.PrizeAmount);
            p.Add("@PrizePercentage", model.PrizePercentage);
            p.Add("@id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

            connection.Execute("dbo.spPrizes_Insert", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            model.Id = p.Get<int>("@id"); //Pulls ID from the p variable that represents the id of the record in the database

            return model;
          
        }
```

With another FileNotFoundException...

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Adding references within the TrackerUI namespace to Dapper, System.Data.SqlClient and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager resolves the exceptions and enables the program to write to SQL no problem. I just wanted to clear up whether that was what I needed to do by default or whether I've missed something earlier and the TrackerUI namespace shouldn't feature references to them. Just don't want to get into bad habits.

Sorry if I've missed any important detail - kinda new to this and have tried to be as thorough as possible but let me know if there is anything else I need to provide.

Thank you for your clarification and help in advance!

Comment: which file is it saying is missing? Which line throws the error? Post the exact exception message, please.

Comment: Added more detail on the exact lines that the code errors and the exact exception message :)